# Wordpress rewrite in subdirectory not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have my WP install in a subdirectory called test-1. I can access my website at www.mysite.com/test-1 but I want to remove the test-1. In my WP root .htaccess file I added:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/test-1/(.*)$ www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it's not working, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test-1/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing.

Comment: That didn't work either. I added a bunch of random text and it broke so I know the file is being read.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to move you Wordpress installed in subfolder /test-1 to be accessible from the main domain mysite.com.
In that case I wouldn't do a redirect, I would re-install in the root folder if your site is not too large. Here's how to do it:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Thanks, but there are reasons it's in a sub directory.

Comment: OK, check this : [link] (https://perishablepress.com/redirect-subdirectory-to-root-via-htaccess/)